# Need to set custom metadata value into dom/html that is coming from IntialFileList

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I am using [InitalFileList](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/session.html) to load files from previous session. My uploaded files will have additional s3 metadata value, which I need to show part of InitialFileList. In the server-side I do add additional metadata to jason object, which I can see in the console output(response).

My question is....
How to set new metadata/property(qq-edit-caption is input field in my template) to HTML display. I do not see any parameter in below callback to get handle on dom. Any help is much appreciated.

```
onSessionRequestComplete(response, success, xhrOrXdr) {
 //
}
```

My HTML template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template-manual-trigger-section1">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
        <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
            <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                <div>Select files</div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="trigger-upload-section1" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Upload
            </button>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
            <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <div>
                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="80" qq-server-scale>                    
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon qq-editable" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-caption-selector qq-upload-caption"></span>
                <span class="qq-edit-caption-icon-selector qq-edit-caption-icon kk-editable" aria-label="Edit caption"></span>                    
                <input class="qq-edit-caption-selector qq-edit-caption kk-editing" placeholder="Caption  here ..." tabindex="0" type="text">
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-update-caption" onclick="captionUpdate(true);">Update Caption</button>

                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">Retry</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete" onclick="captionUpdate(false);">Delete</button 

                <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <input type="text">
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: "How set new metadata/property to HTML display" - what specific HTML do you want to update, and how?

Comment: updated my question with HTML template

Comment: Just line filename, I want to display 'caption' (it is part of file metadata in s3) on each file when all file are loaded with InitialFileList.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure I understand what you are trying to do. You don't need Fine Uploader to edit the DOM. Just use whatever tools you normally would (such as the web API or a wrapper like jQuery).

Comment: let me try that again......1. InitialFileList returns array of files that will be displayed as List. 2. In the List each fine has name, caption (my custom field). 3. HTML template is replicated for each file with variable called FileID,right?. 4. When each file is displayed,how to fill in my custom caption field?

Comment: my mind says....there may be solution like 'qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('qq-edit-caption')[0].value=<set caption>;' BUT, id will not be there as it InitialFileList, PLUS...onSessionRequestComplete does not have FileId access.........sure...this is not a workable solution...but just want to share my mind set.....hopefully you get my problem!

Comment: here is visual [link](http://imgur.com/rEZmVFg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `onSessionRequestComplete` callback handler, you can:

1. Iterate over the entries.
2. Map each entry to a Fine Uploader file ID using [the `getUploads` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getUploads).
3. Get a handle on each container element in the DOM using [the `getItemByFileId` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getItemByFileId).
4. Select the caption input and update it with the desired value.

For example:

```
onSessionRequestComplete: function(response, success) {
   if (success) {
      var uploader = this
      response.forEach(function(item) {
         var id = uploader.getUploads({uuid: item.uuid}).id
         var fileEl = uploader.getItemByFileId(id)
         fileEl.querySelector('.qq-edit-caption').value = item.caption
      })
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank Ray and that looks right approach for me. I would not have figured line#4 in the example. Now, I have trouble with 'this.getUploads' and it errors - this.getUploads is not a function!!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: That worked like a charm and now I learnt the scope of 'this' in javascript too!! Thanks a lot Ray.